# Geo-location search with MYSQL InnoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb, geolocation

i am working on a GEO-enabled application where i have a obvious use case of searching users within some distance of given user location .Currently i am having MySQL DB used. as the User table is expected to be very large by time the time for getting results will get longer (too long in case it need to traverse entire table).

i am using InnoDB as my table do need many things which MYISAM cant do. i have tried mongo and had a test drive with adding 5 million users and doing some test over them . now i am curious to know what MYSQL can offer in same situation as i will prefer MYSQL if it gives slightly near results to mongo .

My user table is having other fields plus a lat field and a lng (both indexed). still it takes much time. can anyone suggest a better design approach for faster results.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo has a bunch of very useful built in geospatial commands and aggregations that will be ideal for your given case of finding users near to a given user point. Others include [within](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) that finds points within a bounding box or polygon. In your case the [geoNear](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) aggregation is perfect and can provide the calculated distance away from the given point.
You will have to code a lot of that functionality with mysql. Then you also have [Postgis](http://postgis.net/) an add on for Postgres. Postgres is the classic open source Mysql competitor and Postgis has been around longer than Mongo and the database presumably behind open street maps, government gis and similar.

But to the problem, you need to use geojson format and [2dsphere](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/) index that you might not be using. Post a single record of your data.